# Resize of SurfaceView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, surfaceview, android-view

I have a small problem with multiple `SurfaceViews` in a `LinearLayout`. How can I resize(shrink) one of the views so that it doesn't create a black space next to it, meaning the neighbour view is being moved next to the resized view. Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose, you might be better off using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html).

With a LinearLayout, everything is **linearly drawn**.

This means that you can only draw things vertically or horizontally, and you have to declare a new Layout inside of that layout in order to change that.

Try reading about RelativeLayout, and post back here if you need additional help.  I'll make sure to get back to you if you don't understand :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm now trying to add the view to the RelativeLayout but they keep overlapping. What am I doing wrong? `StreamSurfaceView surface = new StreamSurfaceView(getBaseContext(), null);  
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);  
lp.width = 50;   
lp.height = 50;
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, other_surface.getId());
streamLayout.addView(surface, lp);`

Comment: I solved the layout issues, thanks. I now have the problem that when I reduce the size of the `SurfaceView` it still leaves the old content in the original position and if I add something in that space it gets drawn underneath.